# Multi-level dropdown to work on mobile bootstrap 5

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I've got a menu with a couple of multi-level dropdowns in Bootstrap 5, got them working on desktop, but on mobile I'm running into an issue that I can't resolve.

The issue is when you try to open the sub dropdown menu, the parent dropdown is closed, so the sub dropdown menu is not visible.

I was thinking this might be done with css `:has()`.

But I don't think I fully understand how that works yet. I need the parent that has a sub dropdown with `.show` to also have the same css.

**What i have tried:**

```
.navbar-nav .position-relative>.dropdown-menu:has(.show) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

and

```
.navbar-nav .position-relative>.dropdown-menu:has(.position-relative>.dropdown-menu.show) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8bufo94k/

Comment: Does this https://www.codeply.com/p/a1dV58wvBV resolve your issue?

Comment: This gets me a step forward, thanks. The dropdown wont close, unless you open another on mobie.